# Reactjs: Unable to start development server using "npm start"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

When i start the development server using `npm start`, i get the following error:

```sh
D:\react\app\app>npm start
    
> app@0.1.0 start D:\react\app\app
> react-scripts start
    
  Starting the development server...
    
  events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
    
  Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
  Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) 
    {
      errno: 'ENOENT',
      code: 'ENOENT',
      syscall: 'spawn cmd',
      path: 'cmd',
      spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
    }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. 
             There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR! C:\Users\Futuresoft\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-04T09_21_21_144Z-debug.log
```

React app package.json file

```js
    {
      "name": "app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

I installed create-react-app globally using:

```sh
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing this error? 
I'm scratching my head from 3 days but unable to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Why did you install `create-react-app` globally when official docs recommend removing it? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: @AjeetShah thanks for response i tried and uninstall it globally and create everything like official documentation but it gave me the same error do you know why?

Comment: It might be due to npm cache issue. You should try cleaning the npm cache or use the **yarn** instead of using npm. `npx create-react-app my-app --use-yarn`

Comment: @AjeetShah not working tried everything again same error

Comment: Are you unable to run using `npm start` this particular react application or you have same problem with any application created with `npx create-react-app my-app`? What is your npm and node version?

Comment: @AjeetShah i just run npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 and it's worked

Comment: So in essence, this mean that you downgraded your `react-scripts` version, right?

Comment: @MwamiTovi yes i think there is problem with the latest react scripts I don't know why?